# What is "th-ruby-include=" directory in rails app root ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is `th-ruby-include= directory` in rails app root?

I did't touch it.

I'm considering add this directory into `.gitigore` or just delete it everytime I see it.

Comment: It is possible that you created the directory when you copied some code and inadvertently pasted it in the terminal when you were doing a mkdir and thought the directory name was on the clipboard, but it was code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a directory in your project, it was created outside of Rails. Likely your editor saved a file without your full understanding.

I would normally say you could delete it, but it's hard to say without knowing the contents. You can always move the directory, run your tests, and if it all passes, delete then.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this directory in my application root. In my case it contained a tree of files that looked related to rvm. I was bold and just deleted it. Everything appears to be fine afterwards.

If I find that it reappears then I will work out what I did to make that happen and I will post an update here.